# ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid while copying from FileStream to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bitmap, filestream, memorystream

I am trying to resize image using bitmap from Memorystream and save to directory. It works on the first run but if i try to update the image second time i am getting ArgumentException.

```
      public IActionResult UpdatePhoto(int id, IFormFile file)
         {
            var company = _context.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            var image = company.Logo;
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/companies", image);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }
             ResizeImage(file, file.FileName);
            company.Logo = file.FileName;
            _context.Companies.Update(company);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

I am getting error in Resize Method

```
   public void ResizeImage(IFormFile  file, string FileName)
     { 
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
          file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
          Bitmap original = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(memoryStream); 
          Bitmap processed = new Bitmap(original,new Size(300,300));
          var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/companies", FileName  );
          processed.Save(path);
      }
```

Comment: the call to `ResizeImage()` must be awaited.

Comment: @canton7 you should be able to update the controller method return type to `Task<IActionResult>` and then await inside the method

Comment: Rather, that call to `CopyToAsync` is asynchronous, and the code doesn't wait for it to complete. Use `file.CopyTo` instead, or add the necessary `async`, `await`, and `Task`-returns

Comment: @zafar You need to do more than that, since `ResizeImage` isn't asynchronous either. You would need to 1) `public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePhoto(...)`, 2) `await ResizeImage`, 3) `public async Task ResizeImage(...)`, 4) `await file.CopyToAsync(...)`

Comment: @canton7 your wish, you can do anyway you want

Comment: @zafar I don't follow. If you simply make the two changes you suggest, you will get compiler errors

Comment: simply use `CopyTo` instead of `CopyToAsync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't be using any of the `async` methods inside the methods which are not `awaitable`. updating your code to following should fix the issue.

```
public void ResizeImage(IFormFile  file, string FileName)
{ 
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        Bitmap original = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(memoryStream); 
        Bitmap processed = new Bitmap(original,new Size(300,300));
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/companies", FileName  );
        processed.Save(path);
    }
}
```